# Map a Vec of structures to another Vec of structure in Rust without cloning

Tags: struct, rust, iterator, closures, map-function

I use a library that has the following structure:

```rust
struct KeyValue1 {
    key: Vec<u8>,
    value: Vec<u8>,
}

fn get() -> Vec<KeyValue1> { /* ... */ }
```

I need to convert this vector to an almost similar vector that has the following structure:

```rust
struct KeyValue2 {
    key: Vec<u8>,
    value: Vec<u8>,
}
```

To be able to convert from one vector to another, I currently use the following code:

```rust
let convertedItems = items.iter().map(|kv| -> KeyValue2{
  key: key.clone(),
  value: value.clone()
}).collect()
```

Although this works, it clones both vectors which is inefficient. I don't need the original `items` vector anymore, so I want to transfer ownership from `KeyValue1` to `KeyValue2`, but I haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` on the `items` vector if you don't need it after the conversion:

```rust
struct KeyValue1 {
    key: Vec<u8>,
    value: Vec<u8>,
}

struct KeyValue2 {
    key: Vec<u8>,
    value: Vec<u8>,
}

fn map_key_values(items: Vec<KeyValue1>) -> Vec<KeyValue2> {
    items
        .into_iter()
        .map(|kv| KeyValue2 {
            key: kv.key,
            value: kv.value,
        })
        .collect()
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65fe5e8bb64adcda42dcf238e634449b)